# Directory outside Wordpress delivering 404 -- just on subdomain

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a very basic Wordpress install, with WP in root and permalinks on.  For external directories I set up, things are working fine, no matter what's in them.

BUT, I recently replicated the site on a subdomain, to use as a dev site.  That site has its own files, and its own database.  On it, any php files in external directories are resulting in a WP-served 404 error.  It serves html files within those directories just fine.

To recap:
mysite.com -- Wordpress site, all is fine

mysite.com/kitties/file.html --> html file outside of WP, fine.

mysite.com/kitties/file.php --> php file, outside WP, fine.

dev.mysite.com --> Wordpress site, all is fine

dev.mysite.com/kitties/file.html --> html file outside of WP, fine.

dev.mysite.com/kitties/file.php -->  php file outside of WP, returns WP-served 404

My .htaccess file is below, and standard, but given that the problem is only on the dev site, I don't know that it has anything to do with htaccess, and wonder if it's an apache configuration issue?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

When Moving / duplicating a site it is usually wise to resave the permalink settings, even when nothing changes.
Did you change the url in the settings of `wp-config`?

After that it is also wise to check the database for urls ([tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)).
Try those and see if the problem still exists.

Comment: Thanks @janw. Yes, I reserved permalinks and even tried turning them off altogether on the dev site, which didn't do anything. I also checked the urls when I first replicated the site.

Sorry if I wasn't clear: everything is working fine within Wordpress-- all urls are working just fine. It's accessing that one directory external to my WP install, and only php files inside it, and only on the subdomain site, that's causing problems.   Thanks!

Comment: It even gives a 404 when permalinks are off? In what folder is the main site and in which folder is the subdomain? I mean folder givven by [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Comment: /home/client/public_html/WPInstaller/wp-content/themes/themename  (<-- to be clear, Wordpress is installed in the WPInstaller directory, but running at the root of my site.  The directory I'm trying to access is one level above /WPInstaller, directly off the root directory)

Comment: So `mysite.com` has the WordPress files in `WPInstaller` but the root is in `public_html` What about the subdomain? This is probably giving the problems.

Comment: same.  dev.mysite.com has the WP files in /public_html/WPInstaller, the site root in /public_html, and the non-Wp files in /public_html/kitties.  And it's just php files in /kitties that are pulling WP 404s.  I'm a a total loss.

Comment: I'm also not sure where the problem lies, Turning them off all together didn't work? Did you try to remove the `.htaccess` to test?